# Eigen Simplicial LDLT Performance for Sparse Linear Systems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen, eigen3

I've been using Eigen for a while, albeit probably pretty poorly.  The reason I say this is because I can't seem to achieve the performance that others are achieving from the library.  I've scoured the forums and dark corners of the internet trying to find solutions to why I cannot seem to achieve great performance, so asking here and hoping that someone can help.  Be aware that I don't have much experience with C++ and proper ways of including Eigen.  Currently I have simply copied the Eigen source into my project directory and included the folder in my include paths.  My project is in Visual Studio 2019.

But on to the problem.  I have some reasonably sized sparse linear systems for which I'm trying to solve A*x = b, where A is sparse (typically 0.05% or far less) and can be anywhere from 10x10 to 400,000x400,000, or larger.  'A' is symmetric positive definite.  The 'b' vector is typically fairly dense, but can be sparse on occasion.

As a benchmark, I have a problem that is approximately 100,000x100,000.  I am pre-conditioning prior to solving potentially numerous 'b' vectors with the same 'A' matrix.  Preconditioning takes approximately 6s.  Solving takes another 0.5 seconds per 'b' vector.  I'm seeing lots of people with problems just as large solving in 0.2 seconds (total, including preconditioning).  So what am I doing wrong?

My code for preconditioning is:

```
    SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double>>* SimplicialLDLT_Preconditioner(SparseMatrix<double>*ptr)
{
    SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::Lower, AMDOrdering<int>>* solver = new SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::Lower, AMDOrdering<int>>();

    solver->compute(*ptr);

    if (solver->info() != Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return solver;
}
```

My code for solving is:

```
double* SimplicialLDLT_Solve(SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double>>* solverPtr, double* f, int numRows)
{
    VectorXd f2(numRows);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        f2[i] = f[i];
    }

    VectorXd x;

    x = solverPtr->solve(f2).eval();

    if (solverPtr->info() != Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    int z = x.rows();

    double* x_array = new double[z];

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        x_array[i] = x[i];
    }

    return x_array;
}
```

Based on all of the samples I've seen, I'm doing the same.

My compiler flags (in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019) are:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /Qpar /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /Fd"obj\x64\Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_USRDLL" /D "NATIVEEIGENWRAPPER_EXPORTS" /D "NOMINMAX" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:SSE2 /Gd /Oi /MD /openmp /FC /Fa"obj\x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"obj\x64\Release\" /Ot /Fp"obj\x64\Release\myProj.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Any insights would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE #1:**
Tried switching compilers to g++ to see if that would help, given that I've read that VS C++ compiler is not fantastic for optimizing.  I used the following compiler flags:

```
-Wa,-mbig-obj -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -finline-limit=1000000 -ffp-contract=fast -march=native -funroll-loops -fopenmp -DNDEBUG
```

I received maybe a 5% increase in speed, but nothing that I would call significant.

Running another benchmark problem that is approximately 200,000x200,000.  Takes approximately 3.5 minutes to precondition using SimplicialLDLT.  Matrix is 0.048% filled (so quite sparse) and SPD.

Comment: Why didn't you enable avx in visual studio? For gcc, did you specifically find that those options worked the best? Usually it is better to use fewer options, for instance `-O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG -fopenmp` (and maybe `-funroll-loops`). Are you sure your problem is as sparse as those you are comparing to, and your computer is as fast? Maybe someone can spot something in the few lines you provided, but without a full runnable test, it may be hard to help.

Comment: @Marc Glisse. I didn't enable AVX in VS because I had read on Eigen's website that modern cpus and compilers should automatically enable vectorization, and didn't think AVX would add much.  Regarding compiler flags for g++, I started very basic like you've shown.  I've probably compiled with two dozen different permutations of compiler settings, using as few as three flags (-O3 -DNDEBUG - fopenmp) to even more than I indicated in the post.  Nothing seemed to make more than a slight difference...as long as optimization of some sort was on.

Comment: @Marc Glisse. And regarding more code...that's literally all the code to precondition and solve.  There are no other functions I've written that get called by either of those.  They simply call the Eigen functions.  I've put timers around each of those individually to make sure I'm testing only those specific calls.  I'm happy to provide additional code if it would be helpful, but I don't know that it would give any other info.  I agree that it might take someone smarter than me looking at the matrix, which I could write out if helpful.  It could be structured differently from other problems.

Comment: I will work on putting together a test with one of these matrices that can be compiled and run by others to see if it is my settings or the matrix itself.  The matrix will have to be written to a file as it is generated through an FEA program.